# How to use the AMS1117-ADJ to get variable voltage?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ldo

I have some questions about the AMS1117-ADJ:

I found AMS117-ADJ  but I am still confused as to whether this is actually adjustable since in the datasheet,AMS1117 on page 2 , it says, 1.2112 to 1.2875. Thats why I wasnt sure if they are referreing to the input voltage or not. On figure 2, they have a diagram for R1,R2. Is this for the ADJ only. Then what exactly is the second column on the table ? Why is the MAX limited to 1.2875?

Comment: Recommendation: Read the datasheet.

Comment: well , I looked at the AMS117, it says it comes in the variable version. But I cant find them  on the commercial sites like ebay. Most of them are fixed. What are the popular ones which are adjustable? I would just like some pointers.

Comment: @redcar, I just searched ebay and found AMS117-ADJ listed twice on the first page of results.

Comment: I found AMS117-ADJ on aliexpress as well as an assorted version. BUt I am still confused as to whther this is actually adjustable since in the datasheet,AMS1117 on page 2 , it says,  1.2112 to 1.2875. Thats why I wasnt sure if they are referreing to the input voltage or not. On figure 2, they have a diagram for R1,R2. Is this for the ADJ only. Then what exactly is the second column on the table

Comment: Ok. Edited the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: Look at Fig 2 in the datasheet. The ADJ pin is carefully controlled to be almost exactly 1.25 V. The output pin is not at the same potential as the ADJ pin. You choose resistors to control the ratio between the OUT pin voltage and the ADJ pin voltage. This is very typical for adjustable 3-terminal regulators.

Comment: So basically I can get 3.3V,1.8V out from the ADJ correct? I have to look into just the resistor value?(Wanted to confirm this)

Comment: What table? there's no table in figure 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking about the table on page 2 (on which figure 2 ain't located), that's beacuse the datasheet covers multiple physical devices, which are actually called that way, i.e have that suffix on their part number. Only the one without any [voltage] suffix is the "officially" adjustable one. But as The Photon explained the difference is somewhat academic, because the adjustable one simply sets its output [typically] 1.25V above its ADJ

[image]

Also the 1117 is made in similar versions by other companies. It sometimes helps to read the datasheets of bigger manufacturers, which will [usually] put more effort in an understandable datasheet. For this device I like [ON's datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP1117-D.PDF) in particular... because it has more data than the others (you'll see that even more clearly when you get to the output cap), and also explains things clearly from the outset:

> This series contains nine fixed output voltages of 1.5 V,
> 1.8 V, 1.9 V, 2.0 V, 2.5 V, 2.85 V, 3.3 V, 5.0 V, and 12 V that have no
> minimum load requirement to maintain regulation. Also included is an
> adjustable output version that can be programmed from 1.25 V to
> 18.8 V with two external resistors.

Note that the adjustable [AMS]1117 does have minimum load requirement. From the AMS datasheet (page 4), that's 10mA.

Also the first two sentences of the following statement in the AMS1117 datasheet (p. 4) are rather misleading because they don't get explained further therein:

> The AMS1117 series develops a 1.25V reference voltage between the output and the adjust terminal. Placing a resistor between these
> two terminals causes a constant current to flow through R1 and
> down through R2 to set the overall output voltage. This current is
> normally the specified minimum load current of 10mA.  Because
> IADJ is very small and constant it represents a small error and it
> can usually be ignored.

Compare with what ON's datasheet says on this:

> The typical application circuits for the fixed and adjustable output regulators are shown in Figures 23 and 24. The adjustable devices are floating voltage regulators. They develop and maintain the nominal 1.25 V reference voltage between the output and adjust pins. The reference voltage is
> programmed to a constant current source by resistor R1, and
> this current flows through R2 to ground to set the output
> voltage. The programmed current level is usually selected to
> be greater than the specified 5.0 mA minimum that is
> required for regulation. Since the adjust pin current, Iadj, is
> significantly lower and constant with respect to the
> programmed load current, it generates a small output
> voltage error that can usually be ignored. **For the fixed
> output devices R1 and R2 are included within the device and
> the ground current Ignd, ranges from 3.0 mA to 5.0 mA
> depending upon the output voltage.**

[image]

Also there is nothing like ON's Fig 23 in the AMS datasheet, even though that's how you'd use the AMS1117-1.5 though AMS1117-5.0 [fixed output] devices, a lacunae that understandably adds to newbie confusion.

Also NXP's diagram of the internals of [theirs](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NX1117C_NX1117CE_SER.pdf), which is generic/general helps fix this idea:

[image]

And if you're really curious, you can "cheat" and adjust the output of the fixed
ones too as shown in [LT's datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1117fd.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Thanks SX. These are nice little regs but not the same as the old LM series that most of us are used to. I've just spent a week and a half head scratching wondering why my voltage dividers don't work. Your post sorts it all out, quite concisely. In particular the menu of other similar datasheets is helpful. Linear give the best detail.
Nice work. Steve

Comment: Small typo: "the adjustable one simply sets its output [typically] 1.25V **above** its ADJ".

Comment: Every '1117 device I have seen requires a *minimum* ESR in the output capacitor. Sometimes the datasheet will have something like "A 22uF tantalum capacitor will be stable at all loads" but this hides the ESR requirement. Put a ceramic there without a series resistor and it may well oscillate (for a short time until it self destructs).

Comment: @bebidek: obviously; thanks.

Comment: @PeterSmith: it's been a long time since I wrote this or dabbled with a 1117. Re-reading, I think I wanted to add something about the output cap when I wrote "you'll see that even more clearly when you get to the output cap".  There's an ESR vs cap value graph in ON's datasheet for instance (fig. 12) with regions of stability and instability. But then I forgot  to mention that in more detail in my answer. I'm guessing I also wanted to say that that graph is missing from AMS datasheet, but I don't have the latter handy to check right now.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the AMS1117-A  . . . .  as an adjustable 1.25v fixed regulator that you "jack up" by increasing the voltage on the middle pin  - the pin we consider "earth" or 0V pin